# Node JS - listen for system events

Tags: linux, node.js, events, system

As per below API doc, Node JS listen for process exit event.
https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit

How can Node JS listen for system event? Such as, USB inserted, CAMERA device inserted into system or any custom events emitted by Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in Linux "Everything is a file" you can monitor the /dev directory for changes. I use this nodejs inotify binding:

node-inotify -  http://c4milo.github.io/node-inotify/